# Can I use @Entity @MappedSuperclass both?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Idea is UserSummary contains few properties needed for general purpose. UserDetail contains all of users properties.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@MappedSuperclass
@Immutable
class UserSummary{}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class UserDetail extends UserSummary{}
```

Comment: Use one or the other. Both is NOT an option

Comment: The question is: why would you even want that? The sole purpose of `@MappedSuperclass` is to handle cases where you *don't want* the base class to be an entity.